# "Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution"

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have changed used version of `maven-dependency-plugin` from 2.8 to 2.10. Now, when I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` I see the following warning:

```
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
```

The version of Maven I am using is

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
```

- Can I fix it or avoid it anyhow?
- Was it always the case that Maven 2 was used for `-Dverbose` output but only now they have added the warning?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce it on newer maven 3.2.5 ? I didn't get the warning on maven 3.2.5 and dependency-plugin 2.10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explanation to your problem can be found at the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

> **verbose** Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency tree. Notice this feature actually uses Maven 2 algorithm and may give wrong results when used with Maven 3.

Have a look at line 245 of [TreeMojo.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.10/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java?view=markup) for version 2.10:

```
if ( verbose )
{
    // verbose mode force Maven 2 dependency tree component use
    if ( ! isMaven2x() )
    {
        getLog().warn( "Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, "
                           + "which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution" );
    }
    dependencyTreeString =
        serializeVerboseDependencyTree( dependencyTreeBuilder.buildDependencyTree( project,
                                                                                   localRepository,
                                                                                   artifactFilter ) );
}
```

It actually prints the warning if maven 2 is not used.

Now look at line 243 of [TreeMojo.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java?view=markup) for version 2.8:

```
if ( verbose )
{
    // verbose mode force Maven 2 dependency tree component use
    dependencyTreeString =
        serializeVerboseDependencyTree( dependencyTreeBuilder.buildDependencyTree( project,
                                                                                   localRepository,
                                                                                   artifactFilter ) );
}
```

The warning logging does not exist there, so:

> Was it always the case that Maven 2 was used for -Dverbose output but only now they have added the warning?

Yes, the warning has been added since version 2.8.

> Can I fix it or avoid it anyhow?

I guess not, that is without ignoring warning log messages, or editing the source code.

However, as you can see, Maven 2 functionality was already used in 2.8. Hopefully you will get rid of it in later versions when they migrate `dependency:tree -Dverbose` to use maven 3 functionality.

Comment: So far they only removed support for `-Dverbose` completely.

Comment: Looks like -Dverbose=true is coming back in maven-dependency-plugin 3.2.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644