# How can I debug maven dependency problems when mvn dependency-tree doesn't work?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am trying to figure out why IntelliJ is using the wrong version (8.1.1 instead of 8.1.2) of one of my project's Java files.  The IntelliJ project is a maven project with many dependencies.

To debug, I tried to use the following from the command line:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=jaffa-ria
```

per the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) on Maven's site.  I see a lot of output about downloading, including some for the `jaffa-ria` package:

```
Downloaded: https://nexus/content/groups/public/org/jaffa/jaffa-ria/8.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (941 B at 3.2 kB/s)
```

However, I don't get any dependency tree printed whatsoever.  The mvn command completes normally with a BUILD SUCCESS, and I only see one warning:

```
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output,
 which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
```

What can I do to find the dependency conflict?  I am using Apache Maven 3.5.0. and Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409087/using-maven-2-dependency-tree-to-get-verbose-output-which-may-be-inconsistent)

Comment: Please try Googling your error message before asking a question here.

Comment: I have googled extensively.  I am actually trying to find an any means of solving the dependency problem.  I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Maven Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper) plugin for IntelliJ or [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) with `dependencyConvergence` rule.

`maven-dependency-plugin` no longer supports displaying conflicts since version 3.0, and as the warning says, older version may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution.

Comment: Thanks.  Maven Helper, and my clumsy experimentation with it, solved my problem.  Maven Helper was showing dependencies on both 8.1.1 and 8.1.2.  I fooled around with the "exclude" menu item and others, and realized that I had inadvertently edited the pom files.  After reverting the pom files, refreshing the UI, and reimporting, Maven Helper no longer showed the dependency on 8.1.1.   I'm guessing that IntelliJ had cached some old version information, and after reimporting all of the project's maven pom files, everything got reset properly.

Comment: Looks like maven-dependency-plugin 3.2.0 will support -Dverbose=true and output the missing dependencies https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try `dependency:tree` without verbose. If this does not work out, you can try to add the "dependency convergence" rule (an enforcer rule).

It will fail if you have conflicting versions of the same dependency and this conflict is not resolved in the `dependencyManagement`. Furthermore, it shows where the conflicting places come from.

Furthermore, if you just want to fix a given version, you can do so in the `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: Thanks!  If I also omit the includes argument, I am now able to see 5 usages of org.jaffa:jaffa-ria:jar:8.1.2-SNAPSHOT.  Unfortunately, I don't see any mention of a jaffa-ria 8.1.1.  Maybe I need to do some IntelliJ cleanup?

Comment: I am no IntelliJ expert, but it might help. Have you also run `dependency:list` and looked for the version there?

Comment: dependency:list also shows uses of 8.1.2, but not 8.1.1.  Thanks to your help with the maven side of things, I'm now thinking that IntelliJ's indexes are confused, despite me having cleared the caches and restarted.

Comment: IntelliJ has nothing to do with `dependency:tree`. You need to install artifacts first, or the Maven will use older ones that are in your repository.

Comment: @Meo that is not true. Maven will never automatically use older ones because it cannot find the ones it is looking for.

Comment: I am not saying that. If you edit your pom in module A, and then use `dependency:tree` on a module B that has a dependency on A, it will use an older version of A that is in your repository (of the same version, e.g. SNAPSHOT), not the one in your project in IntelliJ. An easy mistake.

Comment: But IntelliJ being smart, will use the pom in your project for the dependency resolution. So executions by Maven could use one version, IntelliJ another at the same time.